# Postgresql Crashed after os reboot

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, barman

In Postgresql 9.6 after reboot first I got:

```
2018-04-21 14:36:27 UTC LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-04-21 11:01:15 UTC
2018-04-21 14:36:27 UTC LOG:  invalid checkpoint record
2018-04-21 14:36:27 UTC FATAL:  could not locate required checkpoint record
2018-04-21 14:36:27 UTC HINT:  If you are not restoring from a backup, try removing the file "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/backup_label".
2018-04-21 14:36:27 UTC LOG:  startup process (PID 11768) exited with exit code 1
2018-04-21 14:36:27 UTC LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2018-04-21 14:36:27 UTC LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Which I solved by deleting that file, and then I got:

```
2018-04-21 14:38:50 UTC LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
2018-04-21 14:38:50 UTC LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint record
2018-04-21 14:38:50 UTC PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
2018-04-21 14:38:51 UTC LOG:  startup process (PID 11982) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2018-04-21 14:38:51 UTC LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

Which I resolved by:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_resetxlog -f main
```

Now I get:

```
2018-04-21 17:45:25 UTC LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-04-21 14:53:06 UTC
2018-04-21 17:45:25 UTC LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2018-04-21 17:45:25 UTC LOG:  invalid record length at 1F/8D000108: wanted 24, got 0
2018-04-21 17:45:25 UTC LOG:  redo is not required
2018-04-21 17:45:25 UTC FATAL:  could not access status of transaction 2562642
2018-04-21 17:45:25 UTC DETAIL:  Could not open file "pg_clog/0002": No such file or directory.
2018-04-21 17:45:25 UTC LOG:  startup process (PID 13311) exited with exit code 1
2018-04-21 17:45:25 UTC LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2018-04-21 17:45:25 UTC LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Which I couldn't find any fix, database was recovered via barman few hours ago and was working fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Curious about your config, esp wrt for recovery.  Not sure if you can paste entire config file here. I've had many reboots but never this

Comment: Also did you delete the file or move it? If moved, you could put it back and try several commands to force Postgresql to start. Some googling of invalid checkpoint file error will get you there.  I'm very curious what others will say. I've never had a reboot / corruption before.

Comment: @Dina i had to bring it up and i had a backup so i delete cluster with pg_dropcluster which deleted config files , so i can't access config files sadly

Comment: I would have backed up the file directory first.. just to be able to figure out what happened. Recommended reading (for myself too) http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption